# how to click on next month button in datepicker in protractor

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, jasmine, protractor

enter image description hereI want to click on the next month button in datepicker for testing application.But it is not finding the unique element for this. I have tried using elementor also.But still the issue is coming.may someone help me?

```
div  class="_720kb-datepicker-calendar-header-right"
a class="_720kb-datepicker-calendar-month-button" href="javascript:void(0)"    ng-click="nextMonth()" title="Next"b class="_720kb-datepicker-default-button" b a div
```

elementor given the locators which I used to locate the element are:

```
by.css('a[ng-click="nextMonth()"]')
by.css('a[title="Next"]')
by.linkText('⟩')
```

please refer below link for image 
Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1_qNfzU2s3lZHB6UE1HNDVVQ2s

Comment: Can you provide the some more html ? also the link

Comment: That much long code is not allowing to add.But its clicking on previous button. It is not clicking only on next button.The given html is for next month button. So can you help me?

Comment: Please add whatever you can add . Just provide next month button html. and A screenshot inspecting that element will be enough

Comment: <div class="_720kb-datepicker-calendar-header-right" > <a class="_720kb-datepicker-calendar-month-button" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="nextMonth()" title="Next"> <b class="_720kb-datepicker-default-button"> <b><a><div> This is the html. I am not allowed to post image.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot with inspecting that button which you want to click..?

Comment: Please add it in your question

Comment: `by.xpath(//a[@class='_720kb-datepicker-calendar-month-button'])`
or
`by.xpath(//a[@href='javascript:void(0)'])`

Comment: The Link is private. I cannot open. Please make it public

Comment: Please Inspect that element using `F12` so that I can see the html.

Comment: Can you share me the link ? It would be easy for me to solve your problem

Comment: I have shared. Can you help me now?

Comment: You have shared without inspecting that element. Please click `f12` inspect that button so that i get html code to suggest you. Are you getting me?

Comment: Did you get the image that I have shared with you?with f12

Comment: I am still getting the older image without f12

Comment: Sorry for it.Now you will get the image on the above link

Comment: `browser.findElement(by.xpath("_720kb-datepicker-calendar-header-right")).click();`

Comment: `element(by.xpath("_720kb-datepicker-calendar-hea‌​der-right")).click();`

Comment: `browser.findElement(by.className("_720kb-datepicker-calendar-hea‌​der-right"));`

Comment: Try these three and let me know

Comment: It would be good if you expand the highlighted div and send me screenshot again

Comment: `browser.findElement(by.xpath("//b[@class=“_720kb-datepicker-default-button”]")).click()‌​;`

Comment: Try any of the above provided. I'll get back to you tomorrow morning

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: No. Its giving the error as NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: for all xpath. I am still dealing with issue.

Comment: Can you share me website link? Last way to help

Comment: https://pupilbilling-test.bridge.ac.ke
here is the site. But it requires credentials that I cant share. I can share only this much information.

Comment: How to Login? credentials or email me